# Return Random grade w/ certain percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I'm creating a function to return a string depending on what value the string is i.e. a returns a higher number.

Comment: `print(auotgrader())` or `print(autograder())`? Is this your actual indentation? The code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I changed it.  But is tehre a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Question originally had code, see revision history, this is some syntactical corrections to his original code.

Here are a couple of syntactical problems I see, there are simpler ways but if you want to know the issues with what you have, please refer to other answers for simpler implementations:

1. Don't `import randint` you should instead do either:

   ```
   from random import randint
   ```

   or:

   ```
   import random
   ```

   and when ever you use something like `randint` prefix it with `random` i.e.

   ```
   random.randint(0, 45)
   ```
2. Don't use `+=` instead use the `append` method as in:

   ```
   a.append(randint(0,45))
   ```
3. You don't want `random(a)` instead you probably want a `choice` so rewrite it as:

   ```
   random.choice(a)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
def gen_grade():
    ranges = [(90,100),(80,89),(70,79),(0,69)]
    odds = [0.45,0.35,0.15,0.05]
    rnd_key = random.random()
    for i in range(len(odds)):
        if rnd <= sum(odds[:i]): return random.randint(*ranges[i])

num_grades_to_gen = 25
grades = [gen_grade() for i in range(num_grades_to_gen)]
```

is propbably how I would do this

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to do this is to define bins, just have one random number from 1-100.
then a condition checks:

```
 i = randint(0,100)
 if i in range(0,45):
    return randint(90,100)
 elif i in range(45,80):
    return randint(80,89)
 elif i in range(80,95):
    return randint(70,79)
 else:
    return randint(0,69)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be simplet, but not much:

```
def autograder ():
    bucket = random.randint (1, 100)
    if bucket <= 45:
        return randint (90, 100)
    if bucket <= 80:
        return randint (80, 89)
    if bucket <= 95:
        return randint (70, 79)
    return randint (0, 69)
```